# How to avoid requesting many times the same data from MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb

I have a function that takes from the database the current language chosen by the user, the problem is that this function is ran many times (like 25) when the user request something and I can't avoid that.

This is making my service very slow, so I was wondering what is the best way to solve this problem. Any ideas?

This is what I've done following @JustinEzequiel comments:

```py
@lru_cache
def get_locale(self, guildID: int):
    return db.find_one({'id': guildID})['language'], guildID
```

Comment: Put it in a function and wrap with [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to show how you did it.

Comment: Only then can we show you why "it doesn't work"

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I added the `@lru_cache` decorator to the function that I call multiple times (with the same argument), and it is still slow.

Comment: Yes, but we need to see your function. It may need to be re-written slightly to make use of the caching. I cannot understand why people would ask here in SO yet refuse to post their code.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I've added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to cache the results of the database call. This will allow you to avoid multiple DB hits, allowing you to look up the needed information on the fly. The actual implementation of this will vary depending on the object you're returning from your database.

Comment: I'm fetching a string from the db.